# Remove "add another" in Django admin screen

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Whenever I'm editing object A with a foreign key to object B, a plus option "add another" is available next to the choices of object B. How do I remove that option?

I configured a user without rights to add object B. The plus sign is still available, but when I click on it, it says "Permission denied". It's ugly.

I'm using Django 1.0.2

Comment: Related (but different) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143886/django-admin-disable-the-add-action-for-a-specific-model

Comment: Now possible! `max_num=0`

Comment: @andi This solution, akin to pistache's answer, does not apply to OP's situation (see my comment on pistache's answer for details). This question is similar to the **#1** red circle of this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26425818/1027706

Comment: See ModelAdmin.has_add_permission(request): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_add_permission

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### DEPRECATED ANSWER

Django has since made this possible.

---

Have you considered instead, using CSS to simply not show the button?  Maybe that's a little too hacky.

This is untested, but I'm thinking...

`no-addanother-button.css`

```
#_addanother { display: none }
```

`admin.py`

```
class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    class Media:
        # edit this path to wherever
        css = { 'all' : ('css/no-addanother-button.css',) }
```

Django Doc for doing this -- [Media as a static definition](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions)

**Note/Edit:** The documentation says the files will be prepended with the MEDIA_URL but in my experimentation it isn't.  Your mileage may vary.

If you find this is the case for you, there's a quick fix for this...

```
class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    class Media:
        from django.conf import settings
        media_url = getattr(settings, 'MEDIA_URL', '/media/')
        # edit this path to wherever
        css = { 'all' : (media_url+'css/no-addanother-button.css',) }
```

Comment: Dirty hack not needed, see pistache's answer below

Comment: @ThomasParslow I added a big bold note since my answer is now out of date.

Comment: @T.Stone If you read the OP's question carefully and look at the docs for inline classes you'll see pistache's answer doesn't actually solve the problem. I've added an answer that does.

Comment: @Endophage You are right, it does not apply to OP's situation (see my comment on pistache's answer).

Comment: You can check my answer below for Form and InlineForm solution.

Answer (score 68):

The following answer was my original answer but it is wrong and does not answer OP's question:

> Simpler solution, no CSS hack and no editing Django codebase:
>
> Add this to your Inline class:
>
> ```
> max_num=0
> ```

<sub>(this is only applicable to inline forms, not foreign key fields as OP asked)</sub>

---

The above answer is only useful to hide the "add related" button for inline forms, and not foreign keys as requested.

When I wrote the answer, IIRC the accepted answer hid both, which is why I got confused.

The following seems to provide a solution (though hiding using CSS seems the most feasible thing to do, especially if the "add another" buttons of FKs are in inline forms):

[Django 1.7 removing Add button from inline form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425818/django-1-7-removing-add-button-from-inline-form)

Comment: Can you provide some more info and possibly an example? This doesn't appear to solve the OP's problem. You'd use an InlineAdmin to inline A into B's admin page. The OP wants to prevent creation of B objects from A's admin page. In docs you can see Book has the ForeignKey on Author, but you inline Book into Author, not Author into Book. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: This is not really the answer to OP's question.

Comment: Why ? At least at the time I wrote it, it did remove the "add another" link in inline forms.

Comment: @pistache It is not the answer to the OP question, because in his situation, `A` has a foreign key to `B`, so an `A` object can have **one** reference to `B`, and he is refering to the **+** next to the *B* field in *A*'s form. Basically, if you refer to the image in this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26425818/1027706) OP wanted to remove the plus signe in the **#1** red circle, whereas your answer removes #3 or #4.

Comment: Yes, you're all very right, this answer is total crap, and far from what OP asks. This was written a long time ago, I think my understanding of Django's forms was not as good as I thought at the time. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Where to put `max_num=0`

Comment: Editor's note: while the initial answer is not the solution, apparently it helped a lot of people, likely with another issue. It should probably be migrated somewhere more appropriate, but, lacking a better option, I removed some noise from the answer while preserving the idea behind the original answer being incorrect, and fixed some issues with the post. Once the "outdated answers" feature is rolled out, feel free to mark it as such, it will probably be more on point.

Answer (score 34):

Though most of the solutions mentioned here work, there is another cleaner way of doing it. Probably it was introduced in a later version of Django, after the other solutions were presented. (I'm presently using Django 1.7)

To remove the "Add another" option,

```
class ... #(Your inline class)

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False
```

Similarly if you want to disable "Delete?" option, add the following method in Inline class.

```
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

Comment: This isn't the right solution in most cases -- it not only removes the little `add`, `delete` symbols in from of the ForeignKey field, but also removes the Add/Edit option for the linked model from all places in the admin interface.

Comment: I think this *is* right because it is a subclass of `InlineModelAdmin` (not `ModelAdmin`) and needs to add explicitly to `inlines` of other `ModelAdmin`. And let me fix `has_add_permission` which needs `obj` parameter (`def has_add_permission(self, request, obj):`).

Answer (score 15):

N.B. Works for DJango 1.5.2 and possibly older. The `can_add_related` property [appeared](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9071#comment:18) around 2 years ago.

The best way I've found is to override your ModelAdmin's get_form function. In my case I wanted to force the author of a post to be the currently logged in user. Code below with copious comments. The really important bit is the setting of `widget.can_add_related`:

```
def get_form(self,request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    # get base form object    
    form = super(BlogPostAdmin,self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

    # get the foreign key field I want to restrict
    author = form.base_fields["author"]

    # remove the green + by setting can_add_related to False on the widget
    author.widget.can_add_related = False

    # restrict queryset for field to just the current user
    author.queryset = User.objects.filter(pk=request.user.pk)

    # set the initial value of the field to current user. Redundant as there will
    # only be one option anyway.
    author.initial = request.user.pk

    # set the field's empty_label to None to remove the "------" null 
    # field from the select. 
    author.empty_label = None

    # return our now modified form.
    return form
```

The interesting part of making the changes here in `get_form` is that `author.widget` is an instance of `django.contrib.admin.widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper` where as if you try and make changes in one of the `formfield_for_xxxxx` functions, the widget is an instance of the actual form widget, in this typical ForeignKey case it's a `django.forms.widgets.Select`.

Comment: Are you aware of a way to make this work for `InlineModelAdmin` ?

Comment: Sorry, never tried it for the `InlineModelAdmin`. I'd expect it to be similar though, I'm just not sure how one overrides an `InlineModelAdmin` and I've haven't written a line of Django specific Python since shortly after posting this.

Comment: @Ad N Check my answer below for InlineModelAdmin.

Answer (score 15):

I use the following approaches for **Form** and **InlineForm**

Django 2.0, Python 3+

**Form**

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #...
    def get_form(self,request, obj=None, **kwargs):

        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        user = form.base_fields["user"]

        user.widget.can_add_related = False
        user.widget.can_delete_related = False
        user.widget.can_change_related = False

        return form
```

**Inline Form**

```
class MyModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    #...
    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):

        formset = super().get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
        user = formset.form.base_fields['user']

        user.widget.can_add_related = False
        user.widget.can_delete_related = False
        user.widget.can_change_related = False

        return formset
```

Answer (score 12):

The answer by [@Slipstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50945275) shows *how* to implement the solution, viz. by overriding the attributes for the formfield's widget, but, in my opinion, `get_form` is not the most logical place to do this.

The answer by [@cethegeek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1724599) shows *where* to implement the solution, viz. in an extension of `formfield_for_dbfield`, but does not provide an explicit example.

Why use `formfield_for_dbfield`? Its [docstring](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.5/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L134) suggests that it is the designated hook for messing with form fields:

> Hook for specifying the form Field instance for a given database Field instance.

It also allows for (slightly) cleaner and clearer code, and, as a bonus, we can easily set additional form `Field` [attributes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#module-django.forms.fields), such as `initial` value and/or `disabled` (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52774093)), by adding them to the `kwargs` (before calling `super`).

So, combining the two answers (assuming the OP's models are `ModelA` and `ModelB`, and the `ForeignKey` model field is named `b`):

```
class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        # optionally set Field attributes here, by adding them to kwargs
        formfield = super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == 'b':
            formfield.widget.can_add_related = False
            formfield.widget.can_change_related = False
            formfield.widget.can_delete_related = False
        return formfield

# Don't forget to register...
admin.site.register(ModelA, ModelAAdmin)
```

NOTE: If the `ForeignKey` model field has `on_delete=models.CASCADE`, the `can_delete_related` attribute is `False` by default, as can be seen in the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.5/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L259) for `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper`.

Answer (score 6):

Look at `django.contrib.admin.options.py` and check out the `BaseModelAdmin` class, `formfield_for_dbfield` method.

You will see this:

```
# For non-raw_id fields, wrap the widget with a wrapper that adds
# extra HTML -- the "add other" interface -- to the end of the
# rendered output. formfield can be None if it came from a
# OneToOneField with parent_link=True or a M2M intermediary.
if formfield and db_field.name not in self.raw_id_fields:
    formfield.widget = widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(formfield.widget, db_field.rel, self.admin_site)
```

I think your best bet is create subclass of `ModelAdmin` (which in turn is a subclass of `BaseModelAdmin`), base your model on that new class, override `formfield_fo_dbfield` and make it so that it won't/or will conditionally wrap the widget in `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper`.

One could argue that if you have a user that doesn't have rights to adding related objects, the `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper` should not display the add link? Maybe this is something that is deserving of mention in [Django trac](http://code.djangoproject.com/)?

Comment: +1 This is the best answer. It's not a CSS hack and it doesn't ruin the functionality of the widget for other cases. You can subclass for just the ModelAdmins you want while leaving others alone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Django 2.x and I think I found best solution, at least for my case.

The HTML file to the "Save and Add Another" button is on `your_python_installation\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\subtmit_line.html`.

1. Copy that html file and paste to your project like so `your_project\templates\admin\submit_line.html`.
2. Open it and comment/delete the button code as desired:

`{#{% if show_save_and_add_another %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and add another' %}" name="_addanother" />{% endif %}#}`

I know this problem is already answered. But maybe someone in the future have a similar case with me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on cethegeek answer I made this:

```
class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SomeForm

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        formfield = super(SomeAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == 'some_m2m_field':
            request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
            formfield = self.formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)  # for foreignkey: .formfield_for_foreignkey
            wrapper_kwargs = {'can_add_related': False, 'can_change_related': False, 'can_delete_related': False}
            formfield.widget = admin.widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(
                formfield.widget, db_field.remote_field, self.admin_site, **wrapper_kwargs
            )
        return formfield
```

Comment: Can you explain why/how it's a better solution? It just looks more complicated

Answer (score 0):

The way i fixed a similar situation based on django docs

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.extra

The outcome of the solution is that it lets you add an inline just for that instance. Or in different words: add an inline and just one; no other buttons.

```
#models.py
class Model_A(models.Model):
    ...    

class Model_B(models.Model):
    ...
    relevant_field = models.ForeignKey(Model_A, related_name='Model_B_relevant_field')

# forms.py or someotherfile.py
from django.contrib.admin import StackedInline, TabularInline
    
class Model_B_Inline(StackedInline):
    verbose_name = 'Some Name'
    ...

    def get_extra(self, request, obj=None, *args, **kwargs):
        the_extra = super().get_extra(request, obj=obj, *args, **kwargs)
        self.extra = 1
        if obj:
            the_counter = obj.Model_B_relevant_field.count()
        else:
            the_counter = -1
        self.max_num = the_counter + 1
        return the_extra
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's been pointed out in comments:

```
max_num = 0
```

It has also been confirmed here:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13424#comment:1

PS: This also works for inlines.

Answer (score -2):

django.contrib.admin.widgets.py

(Django Install Dir)/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py: Comment everything between Line 239 & Line 244:

```
 if rel_to in self.admin_site._registry: # If the related object has an admin interface:
        # TODO: "id_" is hard-coded here. This should instead use the correct
        # API to determine the ID dynamically.
        output.append(u'<a href="%s" class="add-another" id="add_id_%s" onclick="return showAddAnotherPopup(this);"> ' % \
            (related_url, name))
        output.append(u'<img src="%simg/admin/icon_addlink.gif" width="10" height="10" alt="%s"/></a>' % (settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX, _('Add Another')))
```

Comment: Hi, wouldn't this remove all links? Anyhow, the question is quite old and a solution was already found in above suggestion. Thx anyway :)