# Django - No add button for TabularInline

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-2.0

I'm using `Django 2.0.9` and I'm creating a simple `TabularInline` ModelAdmin, as follows:

```
class AnswerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Answer
```

This is then used in a `ModelAdmin` object, like so: `inlines = [AnswerInline]`. The `ModelAdmin` is registered with the `admin` site.

Everything works as expected, except that I do not see the ability to add further inline models. Here's what I mean:

[image]

I've seen other inlines where there is such a button, which would dynamically add more fields that I can populate.

I've tried overriding things on the `TabularInline`, like setting `has_add_permission` to return `true` and setting `max_num` to `1000`, but I still cannot get the button to show up.

Would appreciate some outside input here.

Thanks!

Comment: did you check defining `extra = 1` in the class ?

Comment: @Bijoy I did, that does not change things unfortunately

Comment: Try the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310368/why-has-the-add-another-button-disappeared-from-my-django-inlines-when-upgradi)

Comment: @Bijoy I re-ran `collectstatic` and sure enough, the add-option is back. Thank you! Mind writing this as an answer - I will accept it as correct, so you get the credit :)

Comment: thanks man, appreciate that, but that answer helped you, you should upvote that, mine was just a reference. Cant take credit for that ;-)

Comment: @Bijoy I just want to make sure that the question has an accepted answer, so others know that the solution worked. Plus the other question doesn't have an accepted answer. I ended up answering it myself and accepting it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to re-run `collectstatic`. Once I did that, the problem was solved.

This was previously answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310368/why-has-the-add-another-button-disappeared-from-my-django-inlines-when-upgradi), but it was not accepted as correct. I'm writing it here so I can accept this answer so others know that it worked.

Thanks to @bijoy for pointing me to it in the comments.