# django admin inline with only one form without add another option

Tags: python, django, inline

I have a foreign key in model and I am making inline in admin side. I passed `extra=0` to display only one form and its working but I am getting `Add another model` in admin.

I dont want to display `Add another model` in admin just one form only.

How can I do that . How can I remove Add another option from admin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721037/remove-add-another-in-django-admin-screen/13159832#13159832

Comment: Thank you that helped.. awesome

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `ForeignKey`, use `OneToOneField` and it will display just one item without the add another link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69683144/3622344

Answer (score 2):

if you want only 1 inline can be added. You can use `max_num` option.

```
class MyModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MyModel
    extra = 0
    max_num = 1
```