# Django/admin form: how to initialize data with username (access to request object)?

Tags: python, django

I want to cutsomize admin forms but I am lost
below my code

I want to initialize pro_log with username of user connected but failed to access request object
Which method I should overide and how can I get request object
I've read I should override save_model or save_form methods of Modeladmin that return object but how to do that to get access to user in ModelForm?

```
class ProjetFormAdmin(forms.ModelForm):

    OUINON = Thesaurus.options_list(1,'fr')
    pro_nom = forms.CharField(label="Nom du projet")
    pro_log = forms.CharField(label="Log utilisateur", initial='')
    pro_act = forms.TypedChoiceField(label="Projet en cours ?", widget = forms.Select, choices = OUINON, required=False, empty_value=None)

class ProjetAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin):

    list_display = ('pro_nom','pro_log', 'pro_act',)
    form = ProjetFormAdmin
```

Comment: you could just get the user as a foreignKey in the project model and display in the list.

Comment: I found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721037/remove-add-another-in-django-admin-screen/13159832 by overiding ModelAdmin get_form method